# Communicate between parent and child renderer process Electron JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Suppose we have the following 2 BrowserWindow instances created in main process:

```
let fooA = new BrowserWindow({width:800,height:800});
fooA.loadUrl(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, './a.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
let fooB = new BrowserWindow({parent:fooA});
fooB.loadUrl(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, './b.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

As you can see `fooB` is child of `fooA`
Now each browsers window html file is associated with a `renderer` process:
`fooA` is associated with `rendererA.js` and `fooB` is associated with `rendererB.js`

Now let's say I want to send a message from `rendererA` to `rendererB`
Do I have to first send a message to main process and the after the main receives it to inform `rendererB` by using `fooB.webContents.send('message-to-b',"rendererA says hello")`
or is there an easier way since `fooA` is the parent of `fooB`.

Comment: If you're using ipcRenderer/Main, you cannot achieve this, since Electron's ipc packages are intended to send messages between renderer <> main. The easiest way is to use the mentioned webContents method.

Comment: How can i access webContents of `fooB` from `rendererA`?

Comment: Via `BrowserWindow.fromId(<id of fooB>)` or `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()`. First method requires you to send each window the other window's ID. You can listen to the webContent's `did-finish-load` and then use `webContent.send`.