# Communicate directly between two renderer processes in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc, ipcrenderer

I've created multiple windows from Electron's main process and need to pass messages between them. The only way I know to send messages from rendererA to rendererB is by bouncing it to the main process. Is there any way to directly send a message from rendererA to renderB?

Comment: As I know not with the IPC capabilities of Electron.

Answer (score 13):

In a way or another, the main process has to get involved, but communicating between the renderer processes of two windows can be achieved in some kind of straightforward way:

- In the main process, define the window references as properties of the global object;
- In each renderer process, access the reference of the window you want to send a message to by using remote.getGlobal (), then use the send () method;
- Use ipcRenderer.on () the usual way to receive the message in each renderer process.

Here is a [quick example of an Electron app](https://github.com/Mikaeru69/inter-renderer-communication) which does just that:

**main.js**:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require ('electron');
global.window1 = null;
global.window2 = null;
function onAppReady ()
{
    window1 = new BrowserWindow ({ width: 600, height: 500 });
    window1.loadURL (`file://${__dirname}/index1.html`);
    window1.webContents.openDevTools ();
    window1.on ('closed', () => { window1 = null; });
    //
    window2 = new BrowserWindow ({ width: 500, height: 600 });
    window2.loadURL (`file://${__dirname}/index2.html`);
    window2.webContents.openDevTools ();
    window2.on ('closed', () => { window2 = null; });
}
app.on ('ready', onAppReady);
app.on ('window-all-closed', () => { app.quit (); });
```

**index1.html**:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Window 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Window 1</h1>
    <button type="button" class="send-message">Send Message to Window 2</button>
    <script>
        const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require ('electron');
        //
        let button = document.querySelector ('.send-message');
        button.addEventListener ('click', () =>
        {
            let window2 = remote.getGlobal ('window2');
            if (window2) window2.webContents.send ('message', "Message from Window 1");
        });
        //
        ipcRenderer.on ('message', (event, message) => { console.log (message); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index2.html**:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Window 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Window 2</h1>
    <button type="button" class="send-message">Send Message to Window 1</button>
    <script>
        const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require ('electron');
        //
        let button = document.querySelector ('.send-message');
        button.addEventListener ('click', () =>
        {
            let window1 = remote.getGlobal ('window1');
            if (window1) window1.webContents.send ('message', "Message from Window 2");
        });
        //
        ipcRenderer.on ('message', (event, message) => { console.log (message); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tested your "direct message flow" code in my electron app with a mainWindow and a hidden worker renderer process window, where the worker sends a lot of messages to the main window. It work's great but it's way slower than before (~5 times). Before I did send all messages to the main process, which dispatched them to the main renderer window. I guess it has to do with `let window2 = remote.getGlobal ('window2');`

Answer (score 12):

Basicly, in electron, communications between process has three forms:

1. main -> renderer: `webContents.fromId(id).send()` on sender side, `ipcRenderer.on` on receiver side
2. renderer -> main: `ipcRenderer.send()` on sender side, `ipcMain.on` on receiver side
3. renderer -> renderer: `ipcRenderer.sendTo()` on sender side, `ipcRenderer.on` on receiver side

So in renderer to renderer scenario, sender must know the destination's webContents.id, then call it to/from via `ipcRenderer.sendTo()`

---

I've made a electron ipc framework, [electron-ipcfy](https://github.com/vivimice/electron-ipcfy), which unifies ipc calls in all three scenario above.

```
import { ipcfy } from "electron-ipcfy";

interface TestService {
    greet(name: string);
}

const testService = ipcfy<TestService>('test');

if (process.type == 'browser') {
    // Attach implementation
    testService.__attachImpl(
        new class implements TestService {
            greet(name: string) {
                console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
            }
        });
}

// Then you can call it in any process
testService.greet('world');
```

Comment: sendTo will still go through main process?

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the logic of your communication system.

For example, if you always have to send data from BrowserWindow2 to BrowserWindow4, you can declare the **ipcMain** in the BrowserWindow4 and **ipcRenderer** in the BrowserWindow2.

In case you have to send from all the BrowserWindows to all the others, I advice you to use Main process and dispatch message to the BrowserWindows (using the relatives **ID**)

In your **message receiver**:

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
   //manage data
}
```

And in your **message sender**:

```
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', message)
```

[ipcMain doc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md)

[ipcRenderer doc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md)

Comment: What do you mean by declare ipcMain in BrowserWindow4? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I added some info, ask me if you need some clarification :)