# Send Data from render process to renderer process in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing desktop application using Electron,
Scenario is I have 2 BrowserWindow, From FirstBrwoserWindow, I am going to SecondBrowserWindow after button click. i have instantiated SecondBrowserWindow on FirstBrwoserWindow's button click to avoid Object has been destroyed Exception.
As per Electron, if we want to send data between processes we have to use IPC. So actual problem starts here, I am creating SecondBrowserWindow object in FirstBrwoserWindow's renderer file, and for IPC i need to get SecondBrowserWindow object in main process.

How do i get SecondBrowserWindow Object in main.js and use IPC.on there????

Comment: look this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416799/communicate-directly-between-two-renderer-processes-in-electron

Answer (score 4):

The way I've solved this is to pass the data with ipcRenderer from the first window to the main process and then pass it with ipcMain to the second window using `BrowserWindow.webContents.send()`.

It looks kinda like this.

**Window 1**

```
...
// Emit an ipc message with your data
ipcRenderer('your-message', { foo: 'bar' });
...
```

**Main process**

```
...
let window1 = new BrowserWindow(...);
let window2 = new BrowserWindow(...);
...
// when ipc message received pass it on to second window object with webContents
ipcMain.on('your-message', (event, payload) => {
  window2.webContents.send('your-relayed-message', payload);
});
...
```

**Window 2**

```
...
// when ipc messaged received in second window do what you want with the data
ipcRenderer.on('your-relayed-message', (event, payload) => {
  console.log(payload);
});
...
```

Comment: Your approach is regular approach, that is used when we instantiate both windows in main process, here in my scenario i am instantiating second window in renderer process of first window.

Comment: Yes, but in order to get the two windows to talk to each other you have to relay your messages through the main process. The render processes don't have visibility to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in more ways but what I recommend you to:

1) when you receive the input to open the 2nd BrowserWindow in the renderer, **send a message to main.js**

2) **from main.js open the 2nd BrowserWindow** so you can control it and send message to it in a cleaner way.

In this way, you can close the previous BrowserWindow without errors in communication and you have a more **scalable** and **readable** logic for N BrowserWindows.

Comment: Problem is that i am not instantiating 2nd BrowrserWindow in main.js, so i can't get object of it to send message to 2nd window.

Comment: As I said, you HAVE TO instantiate the 2nd from main.js . How can you do that? Instead of  open the 2nd BrowserWindow (BW) from the 1st BW, you have to send from the 1st a message to main.js via IPC and then open the 2nd BW from main.js

Comment: I have done it earlier, but problem was, when i close that window using close menu button and again tries to open it, then i got Object has been Destroyed Exception. To overcome this exception i initialize second browserwindow from firstBrowserWindow's button click

Comment: You can't reopen the same BW object. You have to instantiate another one and you throw no exception.

Comment: reopen in the sense, creating new object everytime

Comment: I don't understand, you can open BW then destroy it and open another without error. If you have some error you are doing some other mistakes :)

Comment: I know if i close BW and tried to open it again on button click, i got Object has been Destroyed Exception. But to avoid this i am instatiating BW object using electron.remote.BrowserWindow reference in renderer process. And it opeing again and again fine.

Comment: I understand what you do but the logic is wrong. The best way is to follow what I say in my first answer, open and close only from main.js. Try to do so, I can't help you more than this