# How to use electron tabs webview as to communicate from browser window to tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to have my communicate between different rendering processes in electron. Rather than have multiple windows I am using electron-tabs which can be found [here](https://github.com/brrd/electron-tabs). To start I simply want my main window to be able to send a message using ipcRenderer to each tab. With multiple windows, you could store each window in a global variable like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416799/communicate-directly-between-two-renderer-processes-in-electron) stack overflow question and then use the web-contents to send a message.

UPDATE: In the electron-tabs documentation, it suggests you can use the tabs webview the same as you would a windows web-contents (see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewsendchannel-args)). Unfortunately, either I am missing something or it is a little more complicated.

[image]

For the code: I have a main window mainWindow.html

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="etabs-tabgroup" >
  <div class="etabs-tabs" ></div>
  <div class="etabs-buttons" style="padding:5px 0px"></div>
</div>
<div class="etabs-views"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/electron-tabs/electron-tabs.css">

<script>
const TabGroup = require('electron-tabs') ;
const electron = require('electron') ;
const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

var tabs = [];

// Create a new tabGroup
let tabGroup = new TabGroup();

// Add 3 tabs to tabGroup
for (var i = 0; i <3;i++){
    tabs.push(tabGroup.addTab({
        src: 'file://' + __dirname + '/tab.html',
        webviewAttributes: {
            nodeintegration: true
        }
    }));

    // Send test message to tabs... !!!! DOES NOT WORK !!!!
    circuitTabs[i].webview.send('testMessage',i);
}
</script>
</html>
```

tab.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  </head>
  <body>
      <script>
        const electron = require('electron') ;
        const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
        const { remote } = require('electron');

        ipcRenderer.on ('testMessage', (event, i) => { alert(`Message from main window to tab ${i}`); });

      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

main.js

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({width: 1200,height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    webviewTag: true
    }
});

mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '/mainWindow.html'));
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', function () {
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/faq#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages

Comment: Yes, I think message ports might be the way to go. Thanks! Let's see if anyone comes up with anything else.

Comment: I tried to use message ports but the example they give uses i-frames contentWindow to post messages. "iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*', [channel.port2]);" But, I don't see 'contentWindow' or any equivalent in the electron tabs documentation.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I can't really be of any help beyond that as I have never tried it. Maybe someone else with experience can chime in.

Comment: I got a little further. The electron tabs have a webview element that functions much like the web-contents. Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. You can get the webcontentsID from the tab and use ipcRenderer.sendTo function.

For the code: I have a main window mainWindow.html

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="etabs-tabgroup" >
  <div class="etabs-tabs" ></div>
  <div class="etabs-buttons" style="padding:5px 0px"></div>
</div>
<div class="etabs-views"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/electron-tabs/electron-tabs.css">

<script>
const TabGroup = require('electron-tabs') ;
const electron = require('electron') ;
const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

var tabs = [];

// Create a new tabGroup
let tabGroup = new TabGroup();

// Add 3 tabs to tabGroup
for (var i = 0; i <3;i++){
    tabs.push(tabGroup.addTab({
        src: 'file://' + __dirname + '/tab.html',
        webviewAttributes: {
            nodeintegration: true
        }
    }));

    // Send test message to tabs...
    var webContentsID = tabs[i].webview.getWebContentsId();
    ipcRenderer.sendTo(webContentsID,'testMessage');
}
</script>
</html>
```

tab.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  </head>
  <body>
      <script>
        const electron = require('electron') ;
        const {ipcRenderer} = electron;
        const { remote } = require('electron');

        ipcRenderer.on ('testMessage', (event, i) => { alert(`Message from main window to tab ${i}`); });

      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

main.js

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({width: 1200,height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    webviewTag: true
    }
});

mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '/mainWindow.html'));
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', function () {
    mainWindow.show();
    mainWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: In `mainWindow.html`, where does `circuitTabs` come from?

Comment: circuitTabs was specific to my application... it should just be tabs[i]. Let me edit that.

Answer (score 1):

Try following this:

> #### `<webview>.send(channel, ...args)`
>
> `channel` String
> `...args` any[]
>
> Returns `Promise<void>`
>
> Send an asynchronous message to renderer process via `channel`, you can also send arbitrary arguments. The renderer process can handle the message by listening to the `channel` event with the [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) module.
>
> See [webContents.send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) for examples.

Look at the docs below for more information.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewsendchannel-args